# Wiring a Play Filter to wrap the error handler

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a Play filter that does some post request logging like this:

```
class LoggingFilter extends Filter with LazyLogging {
  override def apply(f: (RequestHeader) => Future[Result])(rh: RequestHeader): Future[Result] =
    f(rh) andThen {
      case Success(result) =>
        logger.info(s"[SUCCESS] ${result.header.status}")
      case Failure(e) =>
        val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val duration = end - start
        logger.error(s"[FAILURE] ${e.getMessage}}", e)
    }
  }
}
```

I also have `onServerError` handler that maps certain known exceptions to the appropriate `Result`. Unfortunately, the filter is invoked before the error handler converts known exceptions into results, leaving me without the STATUS code I sent to the caller and a stack trace for a handled exception in the logs.

Is there a way to define the filter so that it wraps the request post errors handler invocation?

Comment: We also found ourselves in a similar situation, did you find a solution?

Comment: I have same issue here!

Comment: Still the same issue as of play 2.8, ErrorHandler receive the original, unfiltered/unwrapped RequestHeader